# SwiftUI update global state with fetched data

Tags: swiftui, state-management

I can't update EnvironmentObject with data from network response. In view, initial data are displayed properly. I want class calling to API to update global state with response. Then I got the crash

## Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AppState found.

A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppState may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-30.4/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55#

```
struct GameView: View {
    var location = LocationService()
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("countryRegion: \(self.appState.countryRegion)")
            Text("adminDistrict: \(self.appState.adminDistrict)")
        }.onAppear(perform: startMonitoring)
    }
    
    func startMonitoring() {
        self.appState.isGameActive = true
        self.location.startMonitoringLocation()
    }
}

class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
...
    func getAddress(longitude: CLLocationDegrees, latitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/\(latitude),\(longitude)?o=json&key=\(self.key)")!
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.appState.adminDistrict = response.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.adminDistrict;
                self.appState.countryRegion = response.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.countryRegion;
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

AppState declaration:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isGameActive = false
    @Published var countryRegion = ""
    @Published var adminDistrict = ""
}
```

*post the struct that attaches the AppState environment object to the view hierarchy.*
I have attached AppState in SceneDelegate to ContentView as my root View (if I get it right)

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:ContentView().environmentObject(appState))
```

Should I attach it to every View that modifies AppState?

Comment: What is `AppState`? Post the code for your `AppState` class, and also post the struct that attaches the `AppState` environment object to the view hierarchy. Like the error states, you probably did not attach the object to any ancestors of GameView. Also why is appState an environment object in LocationService?

Comment: AppState declaration:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isGameActive = false
    @Published var countryRegion = ""
    @Published var adminDistrict = ""
}
```

_post the struct that attaches the AppState environment object to the view hierarchy._

I have attached AppState in SceneDelegate to ContentView as my root View (if I get it right)
`            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(appState))`

Should I attach it to every View that modifies AppState?

Comment: Please update your question with that code (formatted) so that it is easier for people to help you. And no, it should be fine in the ContentView as long as ContentView is in the view hierarchy of GameView. Also, what about why you have an environment object in a class?